# close sub-menu dropdown on click anywhere in the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, submenu

I have a menubar on top of my page which show sub-menus when clicked and I want to make disappear the sub-menu on click of anywhere in the page. So far i did code to display sub-menu on click of my menu. Below is the code for the same!

Can somebody help me with the existing code to close sub-menu part on click of anywhere in the page?

Many thanks in advance!

```js
var ddmenuitem = 0;

function jsddm_open() {
  jsddm_close();
  ddmenuitem = $(this).find('ul.submenu').css('display', 'block');
  $(this).find('ul.submenu').css('transition', '1s');
  //$(this).find('div.divsubsubmenu').css('display','none');
}

function jsddm_close() {
  if (ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.css('display', 'none');
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#topnav > ul > li').bind('click', jsddm_open);
  $('#topnav > ul > li > a').click(function(ev) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('current')) {
      ev.preventDefault();

    }

    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active') {
      $('#topnav ul li a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#topnav {
  width: 800px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #191919;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#topnav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#topnav ul li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#topnav ul li a.MenuLink {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: double #161718;
  border-width: 1.3px;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}

#topnav ul li a:link {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#topnav ul li a:visited {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#topnav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#topnav ul li a.active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  background: #e0e0e0;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#topnav ul li ul.submenu {
  float: left;
  padding: 4px 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 30px;
  display: none;
  background: #e0e0e0;
  width: 800px;
  height: 30px;
}

#topnav ul li ul.submenu a {
  display: block;
  color: #00537F;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}

#topnav ul.submenu>li:hover>a {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#topnav ul div {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#topnav li:hover ul div.divsubsubmenu {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#topnav li li:hover div.divsubsubmenu {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}

#topnav div.divsubsubmenu {
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  left: 0;
  width: 800px;
  position: absolute;
}

#topnav div.divsubsubmenu>ul>li:hover>a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <div id="topnav">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="MenuLink" href="#">Admin</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="MenuLink" href="#"> MAC </a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="#">Master Data</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Transaction Data</a>
            <div class="divsubsubmenu">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Company Master</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Location Master</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Size Master</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Admin Data</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="MenuLink" href="#">TPC  </a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="#">TPC1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">TPC2</a></li>
      </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this small code in your javascript:

```
$("body").on('click', function(e){
    var element = e.target.tagName;
    if(element !== 'A') {
        $("#topnav ul li ul.submenu").css('display', 'none');
    }
  });
```

Hope this may help you.